# Cherrypy unable to create socket on WinXP

Tags: python, sockets, cherrypy

Python 2.7, Cherrypy 3.2.0, Windows XP SP3.

Cherrypy app works fine using quickstart when binding to 127.0.0.1 port 8080, however any attempt to bind to actual IP results in

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\wsgiserver__init__.py", line 175
3, in start
    raise socket.error(msg)
error: No socket could be created

... which I assume is related to XP not allowing one to bind to raw sockets.

I have been able to get a socket when running as a service, but debugging a service is not pleasant.

I'm coming from a unix environment, so be gentle. /rimshot

Answer (score 0):

Windows discovery #1: XP Service Pack 2 apparently ceased to allow binding to raw sockets as a "hacker avoidance" something-or-other. So, to successfully bind to a socket one must use python win32 utils and cherrypy to create a windows service, which turned out to be pretty much cake!

An excellent, work-on-the-first-or-second-try howto is found at http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/WindowsService. I have found that this particular windows service was about as hard to debug as a unix daemon ... therefore understand how cherrypy's logging works!